# How to recover Mysql database from backup files

Tags: mysql, database, data-recovery

I have using VPS that had to be re-imaged. my DB was part of it and it was being backup up as the app wasn't in production yet. However, there is some data that I wish to recover on it. the VPS provider is giving me a backup of the image (Ubunto Linux) that has all the files.

Is there a way I can recover my data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mysql data files in Ubuntu are located at `/var/lib/mysql`

To restore your database you need:

1) create new database named as old one
2) stop mysql server
3) copy old database files from `/var/lib/mysql/your_database_name/` to new system
4) start mysql server

Your database will be restored.

Comment: Do I have to rebuild database structure or is it included in those files?

Comment: In most cases you need to install the same version of MySQL.