# How to recover xampp server database file?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp, server

My xampp server was destroyed by virus in my local host. I cannot start this xampp server again. I want to recover my database file. If I start my xampp server and click any files in it, the the following error appears:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142).Click OK to close the application
```

Is it possible to try to recover my database file?

And I was go and see xampp->mysql->data folder to my xampp server database file. It is showing. But main thing is the server doesn't work, only shows the above error.

Comment: if i start my xampp server the following error show in the xampp control panel           "6:06:10 PM  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
6:06:10 PM  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
6:06:10 PM  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
6:06:10 PM  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
6:06:10 PM  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
6:06:10 PM  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
6:06:10 PM  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
"

Answer (score 0):

You should take backup of your data folder and try reinstalling xampp is you are not ready to debug it.

This may be helpful to you [How to recover Data Xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928063/how-to-recover-mysql-database-from-backup-files)